# How to filter a list of cars using react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I've created a `Filter` component using the `react-select` library. I need to filter a list of cars in a separate component `ListOfCars`.

All the data is saved.  But if I use `isMulti` on the `year` select then the console does not show that data. So how should I save it in `array`?

Plus I need to submit the data I saved using the hooks `setYear`, `setModel` and `setPrice` and compare to data I get as props and show the result of filtered cars in the `ListOfCars` component.

```
const Filter = ({ data }) => {
  const optionYear = [
    { value: 2017, label: 2017 },
    { value: 2018, label: 2018 },
    { value: 2019, label: 2019 }
  ];
  const optionBrand = [
    { value: "BMW", label: "BMW" },
    { value: "Ferrari", label: "Ferrari" },
    { value: "Subaru", label: "Subaru" }
  ];
  const optionPrice = [
    { value: 0 + "-" + 3000, label: 0 + "-" + 3000 },
    { value: 3000 + "-" + 9000, label: 3000 + "-" + 9000 },
    { value: 9000 + "-" + 20000, label: 9000 + "-" + 20000 }
  ];
  const [year, setYear] = useState(null);
  const [model, setModel] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");

  const onChangeYear = (e, optionYear) => {
    const onChangeYear = {
      value: e.value,
      name: e.label
    };
    console.log(onChangeYear);
    setYear(onChangeYear);
    return onChangeYear;
  };
  const onChangeModel = (e, optionBrand) => {
    const onChangeModel = {
      value: e.value,
      name: e.label
    };
    console.log(onChangeModel);
    setModel(onChangeModel);
    return onChangeModel;
  };
  const onChangePrice = (e, optionPrice) => {
    const onChangePrice = {
      value: e.value,
      name: e.label
    };
    console.log(onChangePrice);
    setPrice(onChangePrice);
    return onChangePrice;
  };
  const onFilterCars = () => {
    console.log("need filter method");
    const cars = data.filter((item) => item.model === model. && item.year.includes(year) && )); // not sure it is correct but the logic is ..
    console.log(cars);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Form className="white p-5">
        <Row className="form-style">
          <Form.Group
            controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect1"
            className="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12"
          >
            <Form.Label>Brand</Form.Label>
            <Select
              options={optionBrand}
              value={model}
              onChange={(e) => onChangeModel(e, optionBrand)}
            />
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group
            controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect2"
            className="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12"
          >
            <Form.Label>Year</Form.Label>
            <Select
              options={optionYear}
              value={year}
              onChange={(e) => onChangeYear(e, optionYear)}
               isMulti (otherwise it works if isMulti={false} but I need multiple data also)
            />
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group
            controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect3"
            className="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12"
          >
            <Form.Label>Price, $</Form.Label>
            <Select
              options={optionPrice}
              value={price}
              onChange={(e) => onChangePrice(e, optionPrice)}
            />
          </Form.Group>

          <div className="text-center col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <Button className="btn-search" onClick={onFilterCars}>
              Search
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Row>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Question is not clear enough, probably need to illustrate what you are trying to achieve, and what are the problems you encountered plus write them in proper paragraphs if there are multiple questions.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to access the `data` variable at all in this component.  Instead of having a prop `data`, you can have a prop `onSubmit` which is a function of the filters. The `Filter` component can just be responsible for controlling and updating the filter state.

```
const Filter = ({ onSubmit }) => {

  // these should be arrays if `isMulti` is `true`
  const [year, setYear] = useState([]);
  const [model, setModel] = useState([]);
  const [price, setPrice] = useState([]);

  // call the `onSubmit` function with the current state values
  const onFilterCars = () => {
    onSubmit({ year, model, price });
  };

...
```

Let's assume that your `ListOfCars` takes an array of the filtered cars and renders them

```
const ListOfCars = ({ cars }) => {
  // render all of the cars in the props array
};
```

Then your parent component might look like this.  It has a `data` array with all of the cars which we never change.  The local state `filtered` stores the filtered list of cars to pass to `ListOfCars`.  The `handleSubmit` function will be called by `Filter` with the selected options.  We use this to updated the `filtered` state so that `ListOfCars` gets refreshed with the current data.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const data = // some data from somewhere

  // just the currently filtered cars
  const { filtered, setFiltered } = useState(data);

  // function to apply filters
  const handleSubmit = ({ year, model, price }) => {
    // update the filtered state with a new version of the original data set
    // assume that year, mondel and price are all arrays of the selected options
    setFiltered(
      data.filter(
        (car) =>
          // see if this car's model is in the array of selected models
          // include all models if none are selected
          (model.includes(car.model) || model.length === 0) &&
          // same for year
          (year.includes(car.year) || year.length === 0)
        // TODO: filter price
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Filter onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
      <ListOfCars cars={filtered} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
//if year is one value or multiple, it doesn't matter because
//  now yearArray is always an array
const yearArray = [].concat(year);
const cars = data.filter(
  (item) =>
    item.model === model &&
    //will match if any of the selected years is in item.year
    //assuming item.year is an array (not clear from your question)
    (
      yearArray.length
        ? item.year.some((y) => yearArray.includes(y))
        : true
    )
);
```

If data comes from redux then I would get the filtered data using a [selector](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors)

Comment: not from redux. 
data comes as props from parent component

Comment: Then why is this tagged with [react-redux]?  I guess for the same reason it's tagged with [react-native] when it's clearly web code...

Comment: @Xena made an update, if no year was selected then don't filter based on year.